# after overriding the onNavigationItemSelected the navigation items still doesn't call the intnet method

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make the navigation drawer items clikable and call an intent method but its not calling the method and I'm not sure why, when clivking the item I get this error "W/OpenGLRenderer: Points are too far apart 4.000001" , I've added an intent method in the first item to be able to navigate to Main2Activity.class but nothing happens.

```
public class NavActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);




    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}




@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {



    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class));
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

//---------activity_nav_drawer---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="My Offers"
       />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Can you post your activity_nav layout file? You probably  forgot to include the right id in the navigation view.

Comment: i.ve added the menu.xml file that includes the items and its ids